# Pandas groupby results on the same plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am dealing with the following data frame (only for illustration, actual df is quite large):

```
   seq          x1         y1
0  2           0.7725      0.2105
1  2           0.8098      0.3456
2  2           0.7457      0.5436
3  2           0.4168      0.7610
4  2           0.3181      0.8790
5  3           0.2092      0.5498
6  3           0.0591      0.6357
7  5           0.9937      0.5364
8  5           0.3756      0.7635
9  5           0.1661      0.8364
```

Trying to plot multiple line graph for the above coordinates (x as "x1 against y as "y1").

Rows with the same "seq" is one path, and has to be plotted as one separate line, like all the x, y coordinates corresponding the seq = 2 belongs to one line, and so on.

I am able to plot them, but on a separate graphs, I want all the lines on the same graph, Using **subplots**, but not getting it right.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook

df.groupby("seq").plot(kind = "line", x = "x1", y = "y1")
```

This creates 100's of graphs (which is equal to the number of unique seq). Suggest me a way to obtain all the lines on the same graph.

**UPDATE*

To resolve the above problem, I implemented the following code:

```
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
     df.groupby('seq').plot(kind='line', x = "x1", y = "y1", ax = ax)
     plt.title("abc")
     plt.show()
```

Now, I want a way to plot the lines with specific colors. I am clustering path from seq = 2 and 5 in cluster 1; and path from seq = 3 in another cluster.

So, there are two lines under cluster 1 which I want in red and 1 line under cluster 2 which can be green.

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203643/plotting-multiple-lines-in-ipython-pandas-produces-multiple-plots

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to init axis before plot like in this example

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# random df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(25, 3)), columns=['ProjID','Xcoord','Ycoord'])

# plot groupby results on the same canvas 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
df.groupby('ProjID').plot(kind='line', x = "Xcoord", y = "Ycoord", ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is just what I wanted.

Comment: Look at answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139423/plot-different-color-for-different-categorical-levels-using-matplotlib

Comment: This is pretty good, but what if I want the legend to list the ProjID column values instead of "Ycoord"?

Comment: @autonomy you have to plot result of groupby in a cycle and use label argument of plot function to set legend text for each line separately. Example of cycle you may find in next answer of bernie

Comment: @Serenity Thanks, that's what I ended up doing, guess it's 2 lines instead of a one-liner: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,16))
for id, group in seq_data.groupby('id'):
    group.plot(y='timestamp', x='xpos', title='X-position vs. time', ax=ax, label=id)

Comment: This is the 6th thing I tried and it worked perfectly. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 7):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        ProjID=np.repeat(range(10), 10),
        Xcoord=np.random.rand(100),
        Ycoord=np.random.rand(100),
    ))
```

Then we create abstract art like this

```
df.set_index('Xcoord').groupby('ProjID').Ycoord.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
for k,g in df.groupby('ProjID'):
  plt.plot(g['Xcoord'],g['Ycoord'])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

based on Serenity's anwser, i make the legend better.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# random df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(25, 3)), columns=['ProjID','Xcoord','Ycoord'])

# plot groupby results on the same canvas 
grouped = df.groupby('ProjID')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
grouped.plot(kind='line', x = "Xcoord", y = "Ycoord", ax=ax)
ax.legend(labels=grouped.groups.keys()) ## better legend
plt.show()
```

and you can also do it like:

```
grouped = df.groupby('ProjID')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
g_plot = lambda x:x.plot(x = "Xcoord", y = "Ycoord", ax=ax, label=x.name)
grouped.apply(g_plot)
plt.show()
```

and it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example including the ability to adjust legend names.

```
grp = df.groupby('groupCol')

legendNames = grp.apply(lambda x: x.name)  #Get group names using the name attribute.
#legendNames = list(grp.groups.keys())  #Alternative way to get group names. Someone else might be able to speak on speed. This might iterate through the grouper and find keys which could be slower? Not sure

plots = grp.plot('x1','y1',legend=True, ax=ax)

for txt, name in zip(ax.legend_.texts, legendNames):
    txt.set_text(name)
```

Explanation:
Legend values get stored in the parameter ax.legend_ which in turn contains a list of Text() objects, with one item per group, where Text class is found within the matplotlib.text api. To set the text object values, you can use the setter method set_text(self, s).

As a side note, the Text class has a number of set_X() methods that allow you to change the font sizes, fonts, colors, etc. I haven't used those, so I don't know for sure they work, but can't see why not.