# Pandas groupby scatter plot in a single plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is a followup question on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42988389/6347629). There is automatic assignment of different colors when `kind=line` but for scatter plot that's not the case.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# random df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(25, 3)), columns=['label','x','y'])

# plot groupby results on the same canvas 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
df.groupby('label').plot(kind='scatter', x = "x", y = "y", ax=ax)
```

[image]

There is a connected issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21963). Is there any simple workaround for this?

**Update:**

When I try the solution recommended by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for a `label` column with strings, its not working!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 2)), columns=['x','y'])
df['label'] = ['yes','no','yes','yes','no']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.scatter(x='x', y='y', c='label', data=df)
```

It throws following error,

> ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'yes'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: are you limited to matplotlib ? If not try and have a look at `seaborn` it is a wrapper around mpl and reduces the boilerplate code ( and DataFrames are a first-class citizens)

Comment: What about `ax.scatter(x = "Xcoord", y = "Ycoord", c='ProjID', data=df)`?

Comment: Seems to works, Thanks! but why `pd.groupby.plot()` does not work for this? Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, if the 'label' column is string, then the recommended solution is not working

Comment: @MarvinTaschenberger, if the solution is using `matplotlib`, then its great but I would definitely like to know other solutions as well.

Comment: Yes, matplotlib does not understand "categorical" colors. There are other options of course, like create a new column with strings mapped to numbers, or loop over df.groupby and create individual scatters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sns`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 2)), columns=['x','y'])
df['label'] = np.random.choice(['yes','no','yes','yes','no'], 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
sns.scatterplot(x='x', y='y', hue='label', data=df) 
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Another option is as what suggested in the comment: Map value to number, by categorical type:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, c = pd.Categorical(df.label).codes, cmap='tab20b')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over `groupby` and create a scatter per group. That is efficient for less than ~10 categories.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# random df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 2)), columns=['x','y'])
df['label'] = ['yes','no','yes','yes','no']

# plot groupby results on the same canvas 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

for n, grp in df.groupby('label'):
    ax.scatter(x = "x", y = "y", data=grp, label=n)
ax.legend(title="Label")

plt.show()
```

Alternatively you can create a single scatter like

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# random df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 2)), columns=['x','y'])
df['label'] = ['yes','no','yes','yes','no']

# plot groupby results on the same canvas 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

u, df["label_num"] = np.unique(df["label"], return_inverse=True)

sc = ax.scatter(x = "x", y = "y", c = "label_num", data=df)
ax.legend(sc.legend_elements()[0], u, title="Label")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried your second solution, it gives `
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'legend_elements'` this error, can you please check?

Comment: Yes, `legend_elements` is a function [I introduced](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11127) only recently. You need matplotlib 3.1 for that.

Comment: ohh. Great !!! I will upgrade mine. Thanks a lot for your contributions to open source tools :)

Answer (score 0):

Incase we have a grouped data already, then I find the following solution could be useful.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 2)), columns=['x','y'])
df['label'] = ['yes','no','yes','yes','no']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,3))


def plot_grouped_df(grouped_df,
                    ax,  x='x', y='y', cmap = plt.cm.autumn_r):

    colors = cmap(np.linspace(0.5, 1, len(grouped_df)))

    for i, (name,group) in enumerate(grouped_df):
        group.plot(ax=ax,
                   kind='scatter', 
                   x=x, y=y,
                   color=colors[i],
                   label = name)

# now we can use this function to plot the groupby data with categorical values
plot_grouped_df(df.groupby('label'),ax)
```

[image]