# Displaying a shared bar chart from groupby results

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I have this type of Dataframe :

```
    origin  delta
month                
2021-09  admin  -1000
2021-09    ext     20
2021-10    ext    648
2021-11  admin  -1000
2021-11    ext    590
monthframe (32,3)
```

(I reprocessed "month" index from dates in a colum, parsed as datetime initially)
I tried to reproduce
[Pandas dataframe groupby plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494942/pandas-dataframe-groupby-plot)
[Pandas groupby results on the same plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988302/pandas-groupby-results-on-the-same-plot)

with

```
monthframe.groupby("origin").plot(kind="bar",stacked=True, legend=True, xlabel="Month", ylabel="Delta", layout=(20,10),subplots=False)
```

setting month as index before so that it will work as x.

But I can't get it to display bars in the same graph, with various colors.
I only have one graph when I do

```
monthframe.plot(kind="bar",stacked=True, legend=True, xlabel="Month", ylabel="Delta", layout=(20,10),subplots=False)
```

but then all origins are merged into the same months, all is blue and it really isn't informative.

I tried everything I could find (setting axes before; etc, but the plot doesn't even take its named arguments into account).

What to do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `matplotlib`, you have to reshape your dataframe:

```
ax = (monthframe.set_index('origin', append=True)['delta'].unstack()
                .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, legend=True, rot=45, 
                      xlabel='Mois', ylabel='Consommation'))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Output of reshape:

```
>>> monthframe.set_index('origin', append=True)['delta'].unstack()

origin    admin    ext
month                 
2021-09 -1000.0   20.0
2021-10     NaN  648.0
2021-11 -1000.0  590.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand why is this that you can't do it from the start (it seems pretty basic, I actually tried to set origin as index instead of date, or to pass by a pivot table -getting somewhat the kind of result like the output of reshape, but not the right one) nor how it works (because I set index with date precisely to get it as x, so why doesn't it display the origin there is a great mystery for me).
But I guess it should work, so I'm really glad.